# How to Call a wizard from on_change Method Odoo 13?

Tags: python, odoo

What im trying to do is When changing a field name 'my_field'
i need to popup a wizard.

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def on_change(self):
    
   wizard_form_id = self.env.ref('my_module.my_wizard').id
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_model': 'stock.move.wizard',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'views': [(wizard_form_id, 'form')],
                'target': 'new'}
```

But i can't achieve it.
Is there any better way..
Actually what i wanted to do is, when changing 'my_field' i need a wizard to Enter datas in the field named 'my_field2' in the popup and get the value to the active_id.

Answer (score 2):

Current ORM does not allow opening of wizard with onchange. You've to create a button and then you can easily call a wizard.